# IPv6 Link-local address as UDP6TransportTarget in PySNMP?

Tags: python-3.x, ipv6, pysnmp, link-local

I am trying to make SNMP query to agent on link-local address `FE80::1:1%enp0s8`. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pysnmp.hlapi import *

USER_KEY='manager1'
AUTH_PROT=usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol
PRIV_PROT=usmAesCfb256Protocol

userData = UsmUserData('manager', authKey=USER_KEY, 
                                  privKey=USER_KEY, 
                                  authProtocol=AUTH_PROT,
                                  privProtocol=PRIV_PROT)
target=Udp6TransportTarget(('FE80::1:1%enp0s8',161))

g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       userData,
       target,
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB','sysUpTime',0)))

print(next(g))
```

where `enp0s8` is my interface where I would find the agent. However, when I use this I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-SNMP-var.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(next(g))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 107, in getCmd
    lookupMib=options.get('lookupMib', True)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/cmdgen.py", line 122, in getCmd
    addrName, paramsName = lcd.configure(snmpEngine, authData, transportTarget)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/lcd.py", line 107, in configure
    transportTarget.tagList
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/config.py", line 269, in addTargetAddr
    transportAddress = TransportAddressIPv6(transportAddress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 312, in __init__
    base.AbstractSimpleAsn1Item.__init__(self, value, tagSet, subtypeSpec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 74, in __init__
    value = self.prettyIn(value)
  File "<string>", line 217, in prettyIn
OSError: illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton
```

When I don't specify the interface for this link-local address I get time out. Using `snmpget` utility with specifying scope works.

My question is: How can I specify scope of IPv6 link-local address using `Udp6TransportTarget`?

Comment: I just had a look at the pysnmp source code, and it seems that its IPv6 address pretty-print function can't deal with scopes in IPv6 addresses. Probably time to contribute to PySNMP and write a patch :)

Comment: pysnmp patch would be much appreciated! I'll commit it into source tree right away.